# How to remove non existing page?

Tags: views

I have this page where I've put block views on it but I can't seem to remove it. It's not in the menu items.

I don't know what to show you here, so please if you need screenshots ask me.

Examples:

[Ex 1](http://erlinevanhijfte.be/portfolio)

[Ex 2](http://erlinevanhijfte.be/beauty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1 is node 5 (http://erlinevanhijfte.be/node/5). go to it and delete it.
Example 2 is node 102 (http://erlinevanhijfte.be/node/102). go to it and delete it.

To find the node I just looked at the page source which has a shortlink meta tag which shows the node id and also the body tag has a class which shows the node id

Answer (score 1):

Try [delete Ex 1](http://erlinevanhijfte.be/node/5/delete) and [delete Ex 2](http://erlinevanhijfte.be/node/102/delete) when you are logged on.

Comment: Thank you very much, somehow I didn't think of that